# Precision problems with `boost::geometry::difference`

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-geometry

Most of the time when I use `boost::geometry::difference` it does what I'd expect. However, when I have two polygons whose edges are almost coincident, I get some weird behavior. Consider this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/multi_polygon.hpp>

using PointType = boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double>;
using PolygonType = boost::geometry::model::polygon<PointType>;
using MultiPolygonType = boost::geometry::model::multi_polygon<PolygonType>;

template <typename TPolygon>
void printValidity(const TPolygon& polygons)
{
    boost::geometry::validity_failure_type failure;
    bool valid = boost::geometry::is_valid(polygons, failure);

    if(!valid) {
        std::cout << "not valid: " << failure << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "valid." << std::endl;
    }
}

template <typename TPolygon>
void WritePolygonsToSVG(const std::vector<TPolygon>& polygons, const std::string& filename)
{
    std::ofstream svg(filename);

    boost::geometry::svg_mapper<PointType> mapper(svg, 400, 400);

    for(size_t polygonID = 0; polygonID < polygons.size(); ++polygonID) {
        mapper.add(polygons[polygonID]);
        int redValue = 50 * polygonID; // NOTE: This will break with more than 5 polygons
        mapper.map(polygons[polygonID], "fill:rgb(" + std::to_string(redValue) + ",128,0);stroke:rgb(0,0,100);stroke-width:1");
    }
}

int main()
{
    MultiPolygonType polygon1;
    boost::geometry::read_wkt("MULTIPOLYGON(((-23.8915 -12.2238,-23.7604 -10.2739,-23.1774 -7.83411,-22.196 -5.52561,-20.8436 -3.41293,-19.7976 -2.26009,-19.8108 -2.00306,24.8732 2.51519,26.0802 -9.42191,-23.6662 -14.452,-23.8915 -12.2238)))", polygon1);
    WritePolygonsToSVG(polygon1, "polygon1.svg");

    MultiPolygonType polygon2;
    boost::geometry::read_wkt("MULTIPOLYGON(((-8.85138 -12.954,-8.89712 -12.7115,-8.9307 -12.5279,-3.35773 -12.078,-3.42937 -11.5832,-3.50013 -11.0882,-3.57007 -10.5932,-3.63925 -10.098,-3.70775 -9.60273,-3.77561 -9.10737,-3.84289 -8.61192,-3.90967 -8.1164,-3.976 -7.62081,-4.04194 -7.12517,-4.10756 -6.62948,-4.17291 -6.13375,-4.23805 -5.63799,-4.30305 -5.14222,-4.36797 -4.64643,-4.43287 -4.15064,-4.49781 -3.65485,-4.56285 -3.15909,-4.62806 -2.66331,-4.69349 -2.16756,-4.75921 -1.67185,-4.82528 -1.17619,-4.89175 -0.680597,-4.91655 -0.497015,17.8166 1.80166,17.8143 1.61653,17.8078 1.11656,17.8009 0.61658,17.7937 0.116605,17.7863 -0.383369,17.7786 -0.883343,17.7707 -1.3833,17.7627 -1.88324,17.7545 -2.38318,17.7463 -2.88312,17.7381 -3.38307,17.7299 -3.88301,17.7218 -4.38295,17.7139 -4.8829,17.706 -5.38285,17.6984 -5.88279,17.6911 -6.38274,17.684 -6.88269,17.6772 -7.38265,17.6709 -7.8826,17.6649 -8.38256,17.6595 -8.88251,17.6545 -9.38247,17.6501 -9.88244,17.6471 -10.2746,-8.85138 -12.954)))", polygon2);
    WritePolygonsToSVG(polygon2, "polygon2.svg");

    MultiPolygonType differencePolygon;

    boost::geometry::difference(polygon1, polygon2, differencePolygon);
    WritePolygonsToSVG(differencePolygon, "difference.svg");

    printValidity(differencePolygon);

    MultiPolygonType realDifference;
    boost::geometry::read_wkt("MULTIPOLYGON(((-23.8915 -12.2238,-23.7604 -10.2739,-23.1774 -7.83411,-22.196 -5.52561,-20.8436 -3.41293,-19.7976 -2.26009,-19.8108 -2.00306,24.8732 2.51519,26.0802 -9.42191,-23.6662 -14.452,-23.8915 -12.2238),(-8.85138 -12.954,17.6471 -10.2746,17.6501 -9.88244,17.6545 -9.38247,17.6595 -8.88251,17.6649 -8.38256,17.6709 -7.8826,17.6772 -7.38265,17.684 -6.88269,17.6911 -6.38274,17.6984 -5.88279,17.706 -5.38285,17.7139 -4.8829,17.7218 -4.38295,17.7299 -3.88301,17.7381 -3.38307,17.7463 -2.88312,17.7545 -2.38318,17.7627 -1.88324,17.7707 -1.3833,17.7786 -0.883343,17.7863 -0.383369,17.7937 0.116605,17.8009 0.61658,17.8078 1.11656,17.8143 1.61653,17.8166 1.80166,-4.91655 -0.497015,-4.89175 -0.680597,-4.82528 -1.17619,-4.75921 -1.67185,-4.69349 -2.16756,-4.62806 -2.66331,-4.56285 -3.15909,-4.49781 -3.65485,-4.43287 -4.15064,-4.36797 -4.64643,-4.30305 -5.14222,-4.23805 -5.63799,-4.17291 -6.13375,-4.10756 -6.62948,-4.04194 -7.12517,-3.976 -7.62081,-3.90967 -8.1164,-3.84289 -8.61192,-3.77561 -9.10737,-3.70775 -9.60273,-3.63925 -10.098,-3.57007 -10.5932,-3.50013 -11.0882,-3.42937 -11.5832,-3.35773 -12.078,-8.9307 -12.5279,-8.89712 -12.7115,-8.85138 -12.954)))", realDifference);
    WritePolygonsToSVG(realDifference, "realDifference.svg");
    printValidity(realDifference);

    return 0;
}
```

The 'differencePolygon' computed using `boost::geometry::difference` in this code is "valid", though it has an infinitesimally thin region:
[image]

The 'realDifference' polygon is what I output from my "real code" (where the input was slightly different due to (what I'm guessing) is the precision of the WKT writer). You can see this polygon has two infinitesimally small regions, and actually returns not valid (21: failure_self_intersections):
[image]

Is there some kind of tolerance parameter than can be set to avoid these infinitesimally small regions during the difference operation (which apparently sometimes break the polygon)? Or is there a function to "correct" the polygon by removing these self intersections? (I know the correct() function only fixes ring ordering).

Comment: "*Almost coincidence*" What do you mean? Did you mean almost *congruent*?

Comment: @VinceEmigh yes - some edges are "almost right on top of each other"